# Calculate the longest path between two nodes NetworkX

Tags: python, networkx

I'm trying to make a Gantt chard using Networkx. All the nodes in the network are "tasks" that need to be performed to complete the project. With Networkx it is easy to calculate the total time of the project. But the make the Gantt chard I need the latest start of each node.

NetworkX includes one function(dag_longest_path_length) but this calculates to longest path in the whole network. Another function(astar_path_length) results in the shortest path between a source and node, but no function is availed which gives the longest path, or latest start in my case. (if a node as two predecessors it will take the fastest route, but in reality it also has to wait on the second before it can start.

I was thinking of one option.
To evaluate the previous attached nodes and selecting the longest path. Unformal I did not succeeded.

```
start_time=[]
time=0
DD=nx.DiGraph()
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
        DD.add_edge(str(df.at[i,'blockT'])+'_'+df.at[i,'Task'], str(df.at[i,'blockS'])+'_'+df.at[i,'Succ'], weight=df.at[i,'duration'])


fig, ax = plt.subplots()  
labels=[]  
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
        labels.append(str(df.at[i,'blockT'])+'_'+df.at[i,'Task'])
        print(nx.astar_path_length(DD, '0_START', str(df.at[i,'blockT'])+'_'+df.at[i,'Task'])  ) 

ax.broken_barh([(nx.astar_path_length(DD, '0_START', str(df.at[i,'blockT'])+'_'+df.at[i,'Task']), heuristic=None, weight='weight'),df.at[i,'duration'] )],(i-0.4,0.8), facecolors='blue' )
```

Comment: youtube.com/watch?v=a3ww0gwEszo     okay, well this video is about undirected graphs, so your problem is computationally tractable, but still, I like it.

Answer (score 7):

Here is some code that I use.  I agree is really should be part of NetworkX because it comes up pretty often for me.  `graph` must be a `DiGraph`.  `s` is the source node and `dist` is a `dict` keyed by nodes with weighted distances to `s` as values.

```
    def single_source_longest_dag_path_length(graph, s):
        assert(graph.in_degree(s) == 0)
        dist = dict.fromkeys(graph.nodes, -float('inf'))
        dist[s] = 0
        topo_order = nx.topological_sort(graph)
        for n in topo_order:
            for s in graph.successors(n):
                if dist[s] < dist[n] + graph.edges[n,s]['weight']:
                    dist[s] = dist[n] + graph.edges[n,s]['weight']
        return dist
```

Comment: This is a great answer and works a lot faster than iterating all of the simple paths.

Comment: A slightly more general answer to support unweighted graphs and starting from nodes that aren't at the end.
```def single_source_longest_dag_path_length(graph, s):
    dist = dict.fromkeys(graph.nodes, -float('inf'))
    dist[s] = 0
    topo_order = nx.topological_sort(graph)
    for n in topo_order:
        for s in graph.successors(n):
            if dist[s] < dist[n] + 1:
                dist[s] = dist[n] + 1
    return dist
```

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you are using DAGs.

Your problem is rather rare so there is no built-in function for it in networkx. You should do it manually:

`max(nx.all_simple_paths(DAG, source, target), key=lambda x: len(x))`

Here is the full testing code:

```
import networkx as nx
import random
from itertools import groupby

# Create random DAG
G = nx.gnp_random_graph(50,0.3,directed=True)
DAG = nx.DiGraph([(u,v) for (u,v) in G.edges() if u<v])

# Get the longest path from node 1 to node 10
max(nx.all_simple_paths(DAG, 1, 10), key=lambda x: len(x))
```

Comment: Thank you for you comment! 
However this method does not take the weight of the nodes into account, only the number of nodes. So it will not give the latest start but the longest path.

Comment: Then you can use something like it: `max([(path, sum(DAG.edges[pair]['weight'] for pair in list(nx.utils.pairwise(path)))) for path in nx.all_simple_paths(DAG, 1, 10)], key=lambda x: x[1])`